# Make matplotlib contour plot give a filled colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Take this example matplotlib plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx + yy**2)
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contourf(x, y, z)
CS = plt.contour(x, y, z)
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=8, colors='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

This produces

[image]

The colorbar is very hard to read, because it only puts lines for the colors, and the rest is white.

How do I make the colorbar have filled colors, not just lines, like in the [examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it matters whether you use the `CS` from `contour` or from `contourf`.  You want the one from `contourf` to get a filled colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx + yy**2)
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(x, y, z)
CS = plt.contourf(x, y, z)
plt.clabel(CS, fontsize=8, colors='black')
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Note how I swapped the `contour` and `contourf` lines.

[image]

I don't know how to make a filled colorbar using just `contour`.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this is an answer. If you scroll up, you can see the question.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is because the question above seems so trivial (of course `x = 3; x=4; print x` prints 4 not 3; same with `CS=...; CS=...; colorbar(CS)`) I was thinking that the real question was "how to make a filled colorbar from contour" which would be misplaced in an answer.

Comment: No, it's a legit question. I couldn't figure out what was going on, but as soon as I posted the question I saw what was going on, so I posted the answer. Hopefully it helps someone else who does the same thing.

Comment: Is it possible to make a filled colorbar with just contour?

Comment: @weatherguy https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499443/1444073