# How to change colorbar using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, colorbar

if I'm plotting a contour like this, how could I change the color bar for "jet" colour? Is it necessary to call a figure first?

```
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar().set_label(label='values',size=12)
plt.grid(True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a parameter to the `contourf` function:

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

or

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot benson, one more question: It appears like discrete ranges, is there any way to obtain this jet colours in continuous range?

Comment: I believe `contourf` first has to discretize the data by computing levels to display, and those levels are mapped onto individual colors. So if I understand it, it's technically most accurate to keep them discrete. You can specify those levels manually too, as a parameter to the function. If you want to force a continuous colorbar though, you could try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498631/continuous-colorbar-with-contour-levels